# How BroadcastHashJoin exacly work in spark?

Tags: join, apache-spark

I'm trying to understanding how a broadcastHashJoin is executed.
I know that the little table is send broadcast to all node, but next the result is sent back to the driver? 
I'm using the spark ui to undestand how network traffic is managed but i don't get relevant result and the driver result always empty:
[image: Spark ui]
Why i can't see traffic to driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Relation which is to be broadcasted [is collected](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoin.scala#L85) to the driver
2. Collected relation [is hashed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoin.scala#L89) locally
3. Hashed relation is used to [create a broadcast variable](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoin.scala#L91)
4. [Broadcasted relation is used](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoin.scala#L110) to compute join in parallel

Missing data from the driver you see most likely correspond to hashing part which [is not executed inside job](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/joins/BroadcastHashJoin.scala#L86) and doesn't create useful metrics.